# is there any free Google checkout extension in magento?

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, google-checkout

is there any free `Google Checkout Extension or Plugins or Widgets` in `Magento` or what is the simplest way to integrate `Google Checkout in Magento`?

Comment: Belongs to http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Shopping question for Magento modules on a PHP application programming website. NBL on answers here. Questions like this belong over on magento.stackexchange, though shopping questions probably aren't on-topic there either.

Answer (score 9):

Option 1:

Better describe what you're after.  Google Checkout turned off operations on November 20th 2013.

Option 2:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to register at checkout.google.com.
There's a manual on the Magento wiki to get started with Google Checkout and intergrate it into Magento:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/using_google_checkout_with_magento